# How to get started GeoExt?

Tags: geoserver, geoext

I downloaded GeoExt to follow the [Boundless tutorials](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/geoext/).

Already have geoserver installed on my local machine running in Jetty that comes by default in the installer for Windows, with openlayers putting my pages in the `www` folder of geoserver and accessing the browser.

My question is where should I unzip the GeoExt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the [GeoExt quickstart](http://geoext.org/tutorials/quickstart.html):

- Download GeoExt from the downloads page.
- Download [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) 2.10 or later.
- Download the latest Ext 3.x from the ExtJS website.

Place both unpacked libraries in a directory that is published by your web server.

That way you make them accessible from the web:

```
<script src="ext-3.3.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ext-3.3.1/ext-all.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-3.3.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"></link>
<script src="OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GeoExt/resources/css/geoext-all-debug.css"></link>
```